# Utility Class with array

Tags: swift

I'm making a game to learn Swift and Trying to make the code cleaner and better.
I made a class Called `Utilities`:

```
    class Utilities: NSObject {

    //Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Purple
    public let mColors = ["#DA4167", "#81E979","#2B3A67", "#FFFD82", "#3D315B"]

    class func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
        var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

        if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
        }

        if ((cString.characters.count) != 6) {
            return UIColor.gray
        }

        var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
        Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )
    }
}
```

How can I use mColors in another class?
I have another class that where I'm trying to use mColors, this is the line:

```
mRingOne.fillColor = Utilities.hexStringToUIColor(hex: mColors[0])
```

I get this error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'mColors'
```

Comment: Utility classes are almost always a bad decision. `hexStringToUIColor` would probably be better as a `UIColor` extension

Comment: Thanks, I think I will stick to this class for now, as I need to put more methods there.

Comment: This isn't Java. As Sulthan and Hamish have pointed out, Swift lets us extend other peoples classes. We use those whenever possible, rather than making arbitrary utility classes to whole bastard-child methods that didn't fit anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Sulthan says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42030338/utility-class-with-array#comment71235225_42030338), you really shouldn't use a utility class for this (much less a non-`final` utility class that inherits from `NSObject`!).

You should move `hexStringToUIColor` into a `UIColor` extension, which I would advise you also make a convenience initialiser. If you still want a namespace, you can use a caseless `enum` (this is preferred over a `struct` or `class`, as it prevents intialisation).

Also I would advise against using an array to store your hex color strings (unless you actually need to iterate over them for some reason). `mColors[0]` doesn't say "red", so make them `static` properties with actual names instead. They would also probably be a lot more useful as `UIColor` objects instead of `String`s.

Here's an example of those suggestions:

```
extension UIColor {

    convenience init(hex: String) {

        var hex = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

        if hex.hasPrefix("#") {
            hex.remove(at: hex.startIndex)
        }

        guard hex.characters.count == 6 else {
            self.init(cgColor: UIColor.gray.cgColor)
            return
        }

        var rgbValue: UInt32 = 0
        Scanner(string: hex).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

        self.init(
            red:   CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255,
            blue:  CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255,
            alpha: 1
        )
    }
}

enum MySpecialColors {
    static let red    = UIColor(hex: "#DA4167")
    static let green  = UIColor(hex: "#81E979")
    static let blue   = UIColor(hex: "#2B3A67")
    static let yellow = UIColor(hex: "#FFFD82")
    static let purple = UIColor(hex: "#3D315B")
}
```

Now if you want to use your colors, you just say things like:

```
mRingOne.fillColor = MySpecialColors.red
```

Comment: What file should I open for the extension? I'm really new to Swift and trying to practice good programming. Thanks

Comment: @swiftnewbie You could put it in its own .swift file, or just chuck it in at the top of one of your existing .swift files in your project – it will be accessible throughout your project (well, technically the module).

Comment: Happy to help @swiftnewbie :)

Answer (score 1):

Move this line:

```
public let mColors = ["#DA4167", "#81E979","#2B3A67", "#FFFD82", "#3D315B"]
```

...to the "top level", that is, put it where it is *outside* any curly braces (such as those of the class declaration, where it currently is now).

```
//Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Purple
public let mColors = ["#DA4167", "#81E979","#2B3A67", "#FFFD82", "#3D315B"]
class Utilities: NSObject {
```

---

**EDIT** Now I'm sorry I suggested this. Your Utility class is not really a class - it's just a namespace for some constants and functions. Namespaces are good. It would be better, therefore, to have a struct with static members, as suggested in the other answer:

```
struct Utilities {
    static let mColors = ["#DA4167", "#81E979","#2B3A67", "#FFFD82", "#3D315B"]
    // ...
}
```

The syntax for accessing from anywhere would then be `Utilities.mColors`.

Comment: And see my book. Curly braces are a _scope_: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch01.html#_scope_and_lifetime

Comment: But now I have "answerer's remorse". I've modified my answer. The other answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

**set mColors as static:**

```
static let mColors = ["#DA4167", "#81E979","#2B3A67", "#FFFD82", "#3D315B"]
```

and call it:

```
mRingOne.fillColor = Utilities.hexStringToUIColor(hex: Utilities.mColors[0])
```

**You can do static lets to every color:**

```
static let myRed = "#DA4167"
static let myGreen = "#81E979"
```

and call it:

```
mRingOne.fillColor = Utilities.hexStringToUIColor(hex: Utilities.myRed)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I went with the first answer though.

Comment: Actually in many ways this answer is better than mine. Your utility class is not really a class - it's just a namespace for some constants and functions. It would be better as a class (or even better, a struct) with static members. The syntax for accessing would then be `Utilities.mColors`.

Comment: Yeah would better use a struct. Thanks matt