# Swift extension and enum for color schemes

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I create enum in blank swift file for manage color Schemes in my App with this block of code:

```
enum Color {
    case border
    case waterMelon
    case bleu
    case ufoGreen
    case lightBlue 
}
```

In the bottom of that I created a extension base on `Color` enum I just made.

Here the extension:

```
extension Color {
    var value: UIColor {
        var instanceColor = UIColor.clear

        switch self {
        case .border:
            instanceColor = UIColor(red:0.92, green:0.93, blue:0.94, alpha:1.00)
        case .waterMelon:
            instanceColor = UIColor(red:0.97, green:0.38, blue:0.45, alpha:1.00)
        default:
            instanceColor = UIColor.clear
        }

        return instanceColor

    }
}
```

Now the problem is when I wanna use those color I should used something like this:

```
//now : I don't like it.
view.backgroundView = Color.dark.value

//that how I want to be
view.backgroundView = Color.dark

// or like this
view.backgroundView = .dark
```

And I know it's because of the `value` that i declare on extension . but how can I get rid of that?

Comment: You can just use static properties instead, see for example [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42030338/2976878).

Comment: without the need of all this, you simply implement a `struct` with `static` colors.

Comment: @AhmadF But how can I using like this: .dark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use an enum then. If you don't want to enumerate on the values in a switch statement, there is no need for an `enum`. Use a `struct` with constant attributes.

```
struct Color {
    static let border = UIColor(red:0.92, green:0.93, blue:0.94, alpha:1.00)
    static let waterMelon = UIColor(red:0.97, green:0.38, blue:0.45, alpha:1.00)
    // and so on ....
}
```

If you want to extend UIColor to have access to all the other colors of UIColor as well, you can extend UIColor like this:

```
extension UIColor {
    static var border: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red:0.92, green:0.93, blue:0.94, alpha:1.00)
    }

    static var waterMelon: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red:0.97, green:0.38, blue:0.45, alpha:1.00)
    }
}
```

Comment: But how about using like this: `.dark`?

Comment: Oh I didn't know you want to have a extension of UIColor. EDITED.

Comment: In your first snippet above, you might want to let the immutable properties be of the type (`static`) rather of instances of it.

Comment: Thank you @dfri! Good call. Edited.

Comment: You can still use an `enum` with `static` properties. In fact, a caseless `enum` is preferable over a `struct` as you cannot accidently initialise it.

Comment: [A thread related to @Hamish:s comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585344/swift-constants-struct-or-enum).

Comment: There's actually an important reason why one might want to use enum cases instead of a struct. Type safety. If you want to create an UI component that can only have colors from a limited palette, you really would prefer using enum for that, because that immediately limits every user of that component to the palette that you want to stick to.